# Почему курсор выдает некорректный резулльтат?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Приветствую товарищи. Хочу получить максимальное значение столбца по запросу

```
    public Cursor get_data()
{
    return MyDB.query(DB_TABLE,
            new String[] {"MAX(" + COLUMN_FIRST + ")"},
            COLUMN_FIRST + " NOT LIKE ?",
            new String[] {"null"},
            null, null, null);
}
```

Ввожу запись № 1 со значением (к примеру) 10, результат 10

Затем ввожу запись № 2 со значением 20, результат выдает 20

Потом ввожу пустую запись, тогда в ячейку пишется `null`, в этом случае результат запроса должен быть 20, но он почему то `null`.

разве этот запрос не должен выдавать единственное число максимальное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `MAX` автоматически игнорирует `NULL` значения. А для обработки пустой строки Вам нужно сделать проверку при записи значения: если записываемое значение не является числом, вставить `NULL` (потому что пустая запись, `""`, и `NULL` - это разные вещи).

Comment: спасибо за наводку,я совсем забыл, что у меня записывается не `null` а `""`, поэтому условие `COLUMN_FIRST + " NOT LIKE ?",
new String[] {""},` решает мою проблему

Answer (score 1):

Тип данных то у столбца какой? Если строка, то логично, что `"null" > "20"`.

**UPD:** `MAX` вообще скипает все `null`'ы. Проверка:

```
COLUMN_FIRST + " NOT LIKE ?",
new String[] {"null"},
```

вообще не нужна.

Comment: тип `double`. При создании таблицы пишу `COLUMN_FIRST + " DOUBLE, " +`

Comment: @Howling `MAX` скипает `null` значения. Не нужна там првоерка вообще.